# Python. Почему неoбходимо явно передавать объект self при вызове метода из __init__?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, singleton

Необходимо реализовать singleton. Получилось вот такое решение:

```
class MyClass(object):
    _instance = None

    @classmethod
    def get_instance(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls._instance is None:
            cls._instance = super().__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
            cls.__init__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instance

    def __init__(self):
        #so something

obj = MyClass.get_instance()
```

Затем понадобилось вызывать из **__init__** метод **fun**

```
class MyClass(object):
    _instance = None

    @classmethod
    def get_instance(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls._instance is None:
            cls._instance = super().__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
            cls.__init__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instance

    def __init__(self):
        # do something
        self.fun()
        # do something

    def fun(self):
        print("Hello, World!")
```

Но если я явно не передам **self**, получаю ошибку

```
self.fun()
TypeError: fun() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

А такой вариант работает:

```
def __init__(self):
    # do something
    self.fun(self)
    # do something
```

Почему нужно явно передавать **self**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В этой строке: `cls.__init__(cls, *args, **kwargs)` первым аргументом должен передаваться инстанс объекта, а не класс. Из-за того, что у вас в `__init__` вместо `self` попадает класс, вызов `self.fun()` становится эквивалентным `MyClass.fun()`, получается это просто вызов метода класса без параметров, в том числе и без параметра `self`.

Вот этот вариант работает:

```
class MyClass(object):
    _instance = None

    @classmethod
    def get_instance(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls._instance is None:
            cls._instance = super().__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
            cls.__init__(cls._instance, *args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instance

    def __init__(self):
        # do something
        self.fun()
        # do something

    def fun(self):
        print("Hello, World!")

print(MyClass.get_instance())
# Вывод:
# Hello, World!
# <__main__.MyClass at 0x51d1bb0>
```

[ideone](http://ideone.com/uetuOz)